# Transforming JSON data to relational data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display data from SQL Server where the data is in JSON format. But when the select process, the data does not appear:

| id | item_pieces_list |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [{"id":2,"satuan":"BOX","isi":1,"aktif":true},{"id":4,"satuan":"BOX10","isi":1,"aktif":true}] |
| 1 | [{"id":0,"satuan":"AMPUL","isi":1,"aktif":"true"},{"id":4,"satuan":"BOX10","isi":5,"aktif":true}] |

I've written a query like this, but nothing appears. Can anyone help?

Query :

```
SELECT id, JSON_Value(item_pieces_list, '$.satuan') AS Name
FROM [cisea.bamedika.co.id-hisys].dbo.medicine_alkes AS medicalkes
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? Could you show us the schema for your table, please?

Comment: You asked this question earlier today and then deleted it. Please do not do that, improve your question, don't delete and re-ask.

Comment: And please only tag the correct RDBMS... MySQL is not the same thing as SQL Server.

Comment: It's an array so when using `JSON_VALUE()` have you tried using an array index such as `JSON_VALUE(item_pieces_list,'$[0].satuan')`?

Comment: I have this doubt, the data has another child, "Box10". This query will not fetch it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Path is wrong. Your JSON is an array, and you are trying to retrieve it as a flat object

```
SELECT id, JSON_Value(item_pieces_list,'$[0].satuan') AS Name
FROM [cisea.bamedika.co.id-hisys].dbo.medicine_alkes
```

Only in the case of data without the `[]` (array sign) you could use your original query `'$.satuan'`, but since you are using an array I change it to retrieve only the first element in the array `'$[0].satuan'`